# How to use bean on JSF App?

Tags: jsf

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "firstTest", eager = true)
public class test {

    public String testString = "test executed";

    public test() {}
}
```

This is firstTest bean for Jsf.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       #{firstTest.testString}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /helloWorld.xhtml: Property 'testString' not found on type test
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I'm new on JSF whatever I did I couldn't run this. I need help. How can I use beans in the JSF project and where I move them? I'm tired :/

Comment: you must have setter/getter for your variable testString in your managedBean .

Comment: i've one more question. When i want to run the a.html as default. What should i do ? By the way can i create an object of test class in html page ?

Comment: you can edit your **web.xml** file and add this attribute like **<welcome-file-list>** or check this link https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-intro.html **step no. 9**

Answer (score 1):

Change your class to

```
@ManagedBean(name = "firstTest", eager = true)
public class test {

    private String testString = "test executed";

    public String getTestString() {
        return this.testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String s) {
        this.testString = s;
    }

    public test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

In JSF, bean properties are accessed by their get/set methods. So, when you type `#{firstTest.testString}`, it searches for a method named `getTestString()` in bean configured under name `firstTest`, which is the class `test` in your case.

Comment: Thank you, Scorpion helped, yours is true too. can i create an object of this class in html ?

Comment: It will be auto created on first access by default, or upon deployment if you use `eager = true`, which you do. No need for creating it manually. Also, [read this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans.htm) to see what scopes you have available for your beans (when are they created, how long do they live, etc)